# Cannot start Postgresql 12 after pg_basebackup (replication)

Tags: postgresql, centos, backup, replication, timescaledb

I have two DB servers and I am trying to make a Master-Slave replication for my PostgreSQL with TimescaleDB extension.

I went through this process:

1. [Both] Install PostgreSQL 12 on CentOS 7.
2. [Both] Initialize DB and install TimescaleDB. (followed official website tutorial)
3. [Both] Do all the `firewall-cmd`, `postgresql.conf`, and `pg_hba.conf` works.
4. [Master] Create initial database.
5. [Slave] stop PostgreSQL, remove everything in `/var/lib/pgsql/12/data`, and `pg_basebackup` from Master.

   (Command I used: `pg_basebackup -h [MASTER_DB_IP] -D /var/lib/pgsql/12/data -U [REP_USER] -vP -W`)
6. [Slave] set `hot_standby = on` and create `recovery.conf`
7. [Slave] start PostgreSQL to check replication works.
8. [Slave] This error occurs and cannot start PostgreSQL.

```
-- Subject: Unit postgresql-12.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit postgresql-12.service has begun starting up.
Dec 02 17:53:40 localhost.localdomain postmaster[10439]: 2020-12-02 17:53:40.116 KST [10439] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red
Dec 02 17:53:40 localhost.localdomain postmaster[10439]: 2020-12-02 17:53:40.116 KST [10439] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
Dec 02 17:53:40 localhost.localdomain postmaster[10439]: 2020-12-02 17:53:40.116 KST [10439] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
Dec 02 17:53:40 localhost.localdomain postmaster[10439]: 2020-12-02 17:53:40.122 KST [10439] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
Dec 02 17:53:40 localhost.localdomain postmaster[10439]: 2020-12-02 17:53:40.130 KST [10439] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
Dec 02 17:53:40 localhost.localdomain postmaster[10439]: 2020-12-02 17:53:40.142 KST [10439] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
Dec 02 17:53:40 localhost.localdomain postmaster[10439]: 2020-12-02 17:53:40.142 KST [10439] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
Dec 02 17:53:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-12.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 17:53:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 12 database server.
```

As far as I know, this is the last step for replication. But PostgreSQL is not starting after all configuration.

Please ask me any detailed questions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 12 on, PostgreSQL no longer uses `recovery.conf` for recovery configuration.

Instead, you have to add the recovery configuration parameters to `postgresql.conf` or `postgresql.auto.conf` (the latter is commendable for automated editing).

Then create a file `standby.signal` in the data directory, which tells PostgreSQL to start and remain in recovery mode.

Then start the standby server.

Note: the `standby_mode` parameter is gone. Instead, use `standby.signal` if you want standby mode and `recovery.signal` for recovery mode that ends.

Comment: Seriously? Never knew that. Thank you so much! I will try.

Comment: So happy I figured it out. The contents of `recovery.conf` moved to `postgresql.conf` in PostgreSQL 12. And I had to create `standby.signal` as well as `recovery.signal`. It perfectly works now! Thank you Laurenz.

Comment: You need *either* `standby.signal` *or* `recovery.signal` - that is the replacement for the parameter `standby_mode`.

Comment: Actually, it did not work when I had `standby.signal` only. I needed both somehow. But I heard that `recovery.signal` is ignored when there is `standby.signal`. So I created both.

Comment: You need only one of them. I am doing that regularly.